# UITableview freeze the app while scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hai Guys,
         in my app i am using the combination of tabbarcontroller, navigation controller and tableview controller.

The view hierarchy of the app is

```
  UITabBarController
             |
             |_ UINavigationController
                    |
                    |_ UITableView
                           |
                           |_ UITableView
                                  |
                                  |_ UIViewController
```

in first tableview every thing works fine. but in second tableview when i try to scroll up/down the application just freeze. some time it get crash. when it crashes it said EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Actually i have customize the content of the cell will background image and icons the text of the label is parsed from the xml and stored in NSMutableArray the array is a property with retain. This bug really make me crazy.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Comment: Are you putting a TableView inside another TableView?

Comment: no i just push the tableview when i select the cell like [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondTableView animated:YES];

Comment: you should post the code of the seconde table view, esp the customization part. perhaps, there is a problem in the object of customizations.

Comment: Are you loading your images live off the web somewhere in your -cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?  If so, you may want to try loading them asynchronously instead.  That could cause your table to scroll slowly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the datas you are putting in the UITableView.

Did you check with some NSLogs whats inside ?

Are you using big images ? or very long text ?

Comment: image resolution is 320 X 100 its size is 4kb. there is no long text. while creating the table NSLog prints everything. when i try to print the selecting cell contents it just print NULL.

Comment: And if you set basic cell with Hello World and without image. It's the same ? Maybe you could give us some code of the class that is slow ^^

Answer (score 0):

most common reason is that the number of times u putting in table is less for eg .if ur array has 10 items and u r returning 11 items than it will crash .plz post the source code of table so that problem can be found.